# Range of potential difference

Tags: thermodynamics, experimental-physics, electric-current, potential, voltage

What can be the maximum and minimum potential difference that can be applied on any kind of circuit experimentally? Like in theoretical terms we can assume any value but can a potential difference as much as in the range of 10^12V be generated?

Comment: What you are asking to is when so-called **potential breakdown** occurs, is seems. It depends on distance as well and in-between material. A lightning strike is an extreme example of the resistant air becoming conducting for a brief moment. An electric lighter jolting your finger is a more moderate example and can only happen at fairly close range.